# draftjs how to initiate an editor with content

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

Stumbled on this cool text editor, [draft.js](https://draftjs.org/) by Facebook.
I tried to follow the example in Github, but I want to create an editor with content instead of an empty editor.

```
var EditorState = Draft.EditorState;

var RichEditor = React.createClass({
   getInitialState(){
      return {editorState: EditorState.createWithContent("Hello")}
      //the example use this code to createEmpty editor
     // return ({editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()})
   }
});
```

When I run it, it throws an error with the following message "Uncaught TypeError: contentState.getBlockMap is not a function".

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The first argument to [EditorState.createWithContent](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor-state#createwithcontent) is a `ContentState`, not a string. You need to import [ContentState](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-content-state)

```
var EditorState = Draft.EditorState;
var ContentState = Draft.ContentState;
```

Use [ContentState.createFromText](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-content-state#createfromtext) And pass the result to [EditorState.createWithContent](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor-state#createwithcontent).

```
return {
  editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromText('Hello'))
};
```

Answer (score 50):

I've created a set of packages for DraftJS to help with importing and exporting content (HTML/Markdown). I use these in my project [react-rte](https://react-rte.org). The one you're probably looking for is: [draft-js-import-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/draft-js-import-html) on npm.

```
npm install draft-js-import-html
```

An example of how you might use it:

```
var stateFromHTML = require('draft-js-import-html').stateFromHTML;
var EditorState = Draft.EditorState;

var RichEditor = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    let contentState = stateFromHTML('<p>Hello</p>');
    return {
      editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(contentState)
    };
  }
});
```

The modules I've published are:

- [draft-js-import-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/draft-js-import-html)
- [draft-js-export-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/draft-js-export-html)
- [draft-js-import-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/draft-js-import-markdown)
- [draft-js-export-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/draft-js-export-markdown)

Comment: stateFromHTML() is super awesome since it handles html tags like <p> and <strong> BUT, if I pass it a string with <sub> or <sup> tags, it drops them. Any workarounds for that?

Comment: Sorry to say, I don't have a great workaround for that, unless the parser is rewritten to handle more cases. To be honest the whole set of tooling I created (listed above) is terribly outdated and not really maintained anymore.

Comment: Great to have. Initializing the editor with createWithContent is not mentioned in the docs/repo page

Answer (score 22):

There has been some API changes, for clarity these examples uses latest API which is **v0.10.0**.

There are many ways but basically you got three options depending on whether you want to use plain text, styled text or html markup for content resource.

What plain text is obvious but for styled text, you need to use either serialized javasript object or html markup.

Lets start with plain text example:

```
import {Editor, EditorState} from 'draft-js';

class MyEditor extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const plainText = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.';
    const content = ContentState.createFromText(plainText);

    this.state = { editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(content)};

    this.onChange = (editorState) => {
      this.setState({editorState});
    }
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <Editor
        editorState={this.state.editorState}
        onChange={this.onChange}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

For importing styled content Draft.js provides [convertFromRaw](http://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion.html) and [convertFromHTML](http://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion.html) utility functions.

convertFromRaw function takes raw javascript object as parameter. Here, we are using a JSON stringified javascript object as content source:

```
class MyEditor extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const rawJsText = `{
      "entityMap": {},
      "blocks": [
        {
          "key": "e4brl",
          "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.",
          "type": "unstyled",
          "depth": 0,
          "inlineStyleRanges": [
            {
              "offset": 0,
              "length": 11,
              "style": "BOLD"
            },
            {
              "offset": 28,
              "length": 29,
              "style": "BOLD"
            },
            {
              "offset": 12,
              "length": 15,
              "style": "ITALIC"
            },
            {
              "offset": 28,
              "length": 28,
              "style": "ITALIC"
            }
          ],
          "entityRanges": [],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "key": "3bflg",
          "text": "Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.",
          "type": "unstyled",
          "depth": 0,
          "inlineStyleRanges": [],
          "entityRanges": [],
          "data": {}
        }
      ]
    }`;

    const content  = convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(rawJsText));
    this.state = { editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(content)};

    this.onChange = (editorState) => {
      this.setState({editorState});
    }
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <Editor
        editorState={this.state.editorState}
        onChange={this.onChange}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Draft.js provides convertToRaw function so that you can convert your editor's state to raw javascript object for long term storage.

And lastly, here how you do it with html markup:

```
class MyEditor extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const html = `<p>Lorem ipsum <b>dolor</b> sit amet, <i>consectetuer adipiscing elit.</i></p>
      <p>Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. <b><i>Aenean massa.</i></b></p>`;

      const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(html);
      const content = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
        blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
        blocksFromHTML.entityMap
      );

    this.state = { editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(content)};

    this.onChange = (editorState) => {
      this.setState({editorState});
    }
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <Editor
        editorState={this.state.editorState}
        onChange={this.onChange}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: a little aside - I'm confused how data {} object can be used while importing with convertFromRaw() - are there any examples of use cases?

Answer (score 17):

You can use `convertFromHTML` to import html with `createWithContent`

```
import { convertFromHTML, ContentState } from 'draft-js'

const html = '<div><p>hello</p></div>'
const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(html)
const content = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(blocksFromHTML)
this.state = { 
  editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(content)
}
```

As shown in Draft's [convertFromHtml example](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/tree/master/examples). Note that the `0.9.1` version cannot import images, whereas `0.10.0` can.

In `0.10.0` `createFromBlockArray` changes to:

```
const content = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
  blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
  blocksFromHTML.entityMap
)
```

Answer (score 7):

**When you need to initiate an editor with plain text.**

Use [`EditorState.createWithContent`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor-state.html#createwithcontent) and [`ContentState.createFromText`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-content-state.html#createfromtext) methods. Working example - https://jsfiddle.net/levsha/3m5780jc/

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  const initialContent = 'Some text';
  const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromText(initialContent));

  this.state = {
    editorState
  };
}
```

**When you need to initiate an editor with content from the html markup string.**

Use [`convertFromHTML`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion.html#convertfromhtml) and [`ContentState.createFromBlockArray`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-content-state.html#createfromblockarray). Working example - https://jsfiddle.net/levsha/8aj4hjwh/

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  const sampleMarkup = `
        <div>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <i>some text</i>
      </div>
    `;

  const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(sampleMarkup);
  const state = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
    blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
    blocksFromHTML.entityMap
  );

  this.state = {
    editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(state),
  };
}
```

**When you have an array of string and you want to initiate an editor with some of the default draft.js block types.**

You can create array of [`ContentBlocks`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-content-block.html#content)s with constructor `new ContentBlock(...)`, and pass it to `ContentState.createFromBlockArray` method. Working example with `unordered-list-item` - https://jsfiddle.net/levsha/uy04se6r/

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  const input = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

  const contentBlocksArray = input.map(word => {
    return new ContentBlock({
      key: genKey(),
      type: 'unordered-list-item',
      characterList: new List(Repeat(CharacterMetadata.create(), word.length)),
      text: word
    });
  });

  this.state = {
    editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlocksArray))
  };
}
```

**When you need to initiate an editor with content from `ContentState` raw JS structure.**

If you previously saved you content state to raw JS structure with [`convertToRaw`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion.html#converttoraw) (read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46932547/5806646) for details). You can initiate an editor with [`convertFromRaw`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion.html#convertfromraw) method. Working example - https://jsfiddle.net/levsha/tutc419a/

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(editorStateAsJSON)))
  };
}
```

Comment: I was onto this problem of setting current value of Editor that has been passed as HTML string for about 2 days... Thanks man!! Your solution solved it!! Great Work!

Answer (score 4):

In **simple**, you can set raw HTML content to editor from the initial stage or using  `setState` at any time as below.

```
editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromBlockArray(convertFromHTML('<b>Program</b>')))
```

Import the necessary components.

```
import { EditorState, ContentState, convertFromHTML } from 'draft-js'
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be a clean way of doing things with rich functionality. You can add more plugins in the future, export your content as `.md` etc without changing the structure of your component much.

```
import Draft from 'draft-js';

import DraftPasteProcessor from 'draft-js/lib/DraftPasteProcessor';
const { EditorState, ContentState } = Draft;
import Editor from 'draft-js-plugins-editor';

import createRichButtonsPlugin from 'draft-js-richbuttons-plugin';
const richButtonsPlugin = createRichButtonsPlugin();

class DescriptionForm extends React.Component {

state = {
  editorState: this._getPlaceholder(),
}

_getPlaceholder() {
  const placeholder = 'Write something here';
  const contentHTML = DraftPasteProcessor.processHTML(placeholder);
  const state = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentHTML);
  return Draft.EditorState.createWithContent(state);
}

_onChange(editorState) {
  this.setState({
    editorState,
  });
}

render () {
    let { editorState } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
          <Editor
            editorState={editorState}
            onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)}
            spellCheck={false}
            plugins={[richButtonsPlugin, videoPlugin]}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? My answer is correct. I asked to initiate with contentState rather than string as asked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the initial value to your edtitorState just by add the folwwling code if you want to set it with HTML format

```
this.state = {
  editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(
    ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
      convertFromHTML('<p>My initial content.</p>')
    )
  ),
}
```

Comment: where did you get `convertFromHTML` from?

Comment: from draft.js itself https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion

Answer (score 0):

for **Nextjs**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { EditorState, convertToRaw, ContentState, convertFromHTML } from 'draft- 
js';
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";

const Editor = dynamic(
() => import('react-draft-wysiwyg').then(mod => mod.Editor),
{ ssr: false }
)

let htmlToDraft = null;
if (typeof window === 'object') {
htmlToDraft = require('html-to-draftjs').default;
}

export default class EditorConvertToHTML extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
        contentState: ""
     }
    }

 componentDidMount() {

    const html = '<p>Hey this <strong>editor</strong> rocks d</p>';
    const contentBlock = htmlToDraft(html);
    console.log(contentBlock)
     if (contentBlock) {
        const contentState = 
        ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlock.contentBlocks);
        const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
        console.log(editorState)
        this.setState(
            {
                editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(
                    ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
                        convertFromHTML(html)
                    )
                )
            }
          )
         }
        } 

     onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
     this.setState({
        editorState,
      });
     };

    render() {
    const { editorState } = this.state;
    console.log(this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent())
    return (
        <div>
            <Editor
                editorState={editorState}
                wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
                editorClassName="demo-editor"
                onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
            />
            <textarea
                disabled
                value= 
      {draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))}
            />
         </div>
        );
      }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **insertText()**

```
insertContent(){
    const contentState=editorState.getCurrentState();
    const selection=editorState.getSelection();
    const newContentState=Modifer.insertText(contentState,selection,'hello');
    const nextEditorState=EditorState.push(editorState,newContentState,'insert-character')
    setEditorState(nextEditorState)
}
```