# draft-js toJS and fromJS EditorState

Tags: draftjs

Trying to serialize & deserialize draft-js EditorState. Couldn't make **fromJS** create EditorState.
[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/draft-js-tofromjs-22p6h?file=/src/App.js)

What I'm trying to achive is to re-create EditorState from serialized javascript object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EditorState maintains undo and redo stacks of ContentState objects. The current ContentState provides, well, the current content:

```
myContentState = myEditorState.getCurrentContent();
```

It sounds like what you really want to do is convert the EditorState's current ContentState to raw JS.

This is achieved via the utility function [convertToRaw()](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion):

```
myRawJSState = convertToRaw(myContentState);
```

When it's time to reapply the contents, the companion utility function is convertFromRaw():

```
myRestorableState = convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(myRawJSState));
```

Import details and additional info appear on [this SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499858/draft-js-persist-editorcontent-to-database).

A detailed example appears at [ReactRocket](https://reactrocket.com/post/draft-js-persisting-content/).

Good luck. This isn't easy to parse from the documentation until you know the name of the method you're looking for!