# Input text in draft.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, robotframework, draftjs

I'm doing automation test and I need to input text in a text field, but the problem is there is no 'input' to do this.

This one won't work:

```
document.querySelector([class*=modal-dialog] [class*=AddCitation_] [class*='DraftEditorPlaceholder']).value='Hello World'
```

Does any one know how to input text in draft.js?

Comment: This should help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884112/draftjs-how-to-initiate-an-editor-with-content

Comment: How is it not working? Is there an error thrown?

Comment: Could you refer to this issue https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/1044

Comment: It's react based and doesn't consist of an input field so I guess changing it won't work if it doesn't update the state. You could update the keyDown binding function but that's just a guess from my side

Comment: @Nikolai what are the trials using robot framework? are you really using it?

Comment: Yes, I'm using it. I'm stuck here now with input.

Comment: Why don't you update the state of draft.js using `EditorState.createWithContent(createFromText('Hello World'))` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use document.execCommand("insertHTML", "html string here", false)
As you can see draft js uses contenteditable property of div to write text
So if you want to automate tests with draftjs insert any sample html string with command
so you have a sample text in draft editor now you can perform tests
Read this
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried also 'document.execCommand("insertText", false, "Hello World!"'

Answer (score 1):

Let's first understand the code you have written:

```
document.querySelector([class*=modal-dialog] [class*=AddCitation_] [class*='DraftEditorPlaceholder']).value='Hello World'
```

This code attempts to:

- get the first element
- which has a class containing 'DraftEditorPlaceholder' and
- which has an ancestor having a class containing AddCitation_ which
- has an ancestor having a class containing modal-dialog

So, you will first need to ensure that the element you try to edit is inside an element having a class containing modal-dialog. In your screenshot we cannot see such an ancestor element, the root having a class of modal-content. If the selector you have written does not find an element, then an error will be thrown when you try to assign a value to any of its attributes, like `value` in this case. You have an element having a class of styles_AddCitation__3_D5j, which is the child of the element of the class of modal-content. You have an element having a class of public-DraftEditorPlaceholder-root, which, assuming that you have a class containing the modal-dialog text being its ancestor, then the selector will find it. However, this is the sibling of the element which you seem to expect to find with your query. So, you will need to sort out where you intend to put your text into.

Now, assuming that you have sorted your selector out and there is a span in the element you are talking about, you will need to write span at the end of your selector, with a space before it. Also, in this case you will need to set `innerText` instead of `value` to your desired value. If the target element is an input, then setting a value should suffice.

Another possible problem is that your Javascript code might run before the structure is actually generated, hence not being able to set attributes of elements which do not exist yet. So you will also need to make sure that your structure is in place indeed when this Javascript code runs.

Answer (score 1):

```
 const screen = document.getElementById("screen");//get span ID
screen.innerHTML += `<span class="screen" >${
      this.textContent
    }</span>`);//add text content


<body>
    <h1>CALCULATOR</h1>
    <!-- <div class="container"> -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="column2" id="screen">
        <!-- <span class="screen"></span> -->
      </div>
```

I used this to insert span tags into a div tag.
I'm only a beginner so it might not be optimal
I used this while experimenting with JS on a simple calculator, because I wanted to see if it could work without using an input tag.
please let me know if this helps as it will also help me to see if my understanding is good